# remove everything between two square brackets

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace, phpbb

I've been trying to remove some text... between two sets of brackts... for two hours i have tried everything... i've been to existing questions here and the answers don't work for me... so here goes
what i have

```
 [attachment=0:randomID]<!-- ia0 -->randomIMGnam.png<!-- ia0 -->[/attachment:randomID]
```

i really want to remove all of this from the beginning of a string i was able to remove everything inside the brackets but failed everytime to get rid of the image name

Yes this is from phpbb i've pulled it from my DB no problem but don't want it to be displayed when i echo it.

thanks in advance i really hope I really hope someone can help

edit: what i've tried
1. `$extension_pos = strrpos($entry, '<!-- ia0 -->'); // find position of the last dot, so where the extension starts
$output = substr($entry, 0, $extension_pos) . '' . substr($entry, $extension_pos);`

2.`$output= preg_replace('#\].*?\[#', '', $entry);`

1. `$output = preg_replace('/\[[^]]*\]/', '', $entry);`
2. `$output explode(']', $entry);`
3. `$imagename = preg_replace('#([attachment.*?]).*?([/attachment.*?])#', '$1$2', $entry);`

Comment: Post what have you tried..

Comment: you can user `REGEX` for this

Comment: @Luke What would be the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regular expression as in example:

```
<?php
    $string = 'test [attachment=0:randomID]randomIMGnam.png[/attachment:randomID] test2 [something]
    test3

    [/something] test4';


    echo preg_replace('#(\[(.*)\](.*)\[/.*\])#Us','',$string);
    // output test test2 test4 


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to replace:

```
$string = ' [attachment=0:randomID]<!-- ia0 -->randomIMGnam.png<!-- ia0 -->[/attachment:randomID]';
$string = preg_replace('/\[(.*?)\]/', '', $string);
```

Comment: Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g'

Comment: @LukeVyner:- You can remove the `g` as g is implicit with preg_replace(), you don't need to include it

Answer (score 0):

Using regex might be heavy for this kind of task.
You could instead use a simple reasoning, whenever you meet a open bracket increment a counter by one, whenever you meet a close bracket decrement the counter by one.

And as long as your counter is > 0 just ignore the characters.